# How can I share Pivot Cache between more Apache POI Pivot?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot

I have problems when I try to open my Apache POI excel file which consists on a big amount of data (600.000 / 700000 lines) that feeds three pivots generated in three different sheets (using streaming SXSSFWorkbook).

When I try to open the created Excel di MSExcel, this message comes out: "excel can not complete this activity with the available Excel resources ... try to close something ...".
So, to save resources, I tried to share the cache between the first two pivots: OK! It's better!
But when I try to share the cache even with the third one, MSExcel gives me errors and tries to restore but with wrong results.

**Any solution to share cache with more than two pivots with the same data source? Or am I doing something wrong?**

Here is the code:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFPivotTable firstPivot = preparefirstPivot(...);
XSSFPivotTable secondPivot = preparesecondPivot(...);
XSSFPivotTable thirdPivot = preparethirdPivot(...);

/* START: shared cache */
/* I remove from workbook all PivotCaches except the firstPivot one */
long firstPivotCacheId = firstPivot.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getCacheId();
List<CTPivotCache> ctPivotCacheList = wb.getCTWorkbook().getPivotCaches().getPivotCacheList();
for (int i = 0; i < ctPivotCacheList.size(); i++) {
    CTPivotCache ctPivotCache = ctPivotCacheList.get(i);
    if(ctPivotCache.getCacheId() != firstPivotChaceId ) {
        wb.getCTWorkbook().getPivotCaches().removePivotCache(i);
    }
}
/* I share the firstPivot cache with the other pivots */
/* work! OK! */
secondPivot.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setCacheId(firstPivotCacheId);
secondPivot.setPivotCache(firstPivot.getPivotCache());
/* here does not work! why?!??!! */
thirdPivot.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setCacheId(firstPivotCacheId);
thirdPivot.setPivotCache(firstPivot.getPivotCache());
```

Something wrong?
Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFPivotTable firstPivot = preparefirstPivot(...);
XSSFPivotTable secondPivot = preparesecondPivot(...);
XSSFPivotTable thirdPivot = preparethirdPivot(...);

/* START: shared cache */
                List<CTPivotCache> ctPivotCacheList = wb.getCTWorkbook().getPivotCaches().getPivotCacheList();
                if (ctPivotCacheList != null && ctPivotCacheList.size() > 1) {
                    /* useful only with more than one PivotCache */
                    List<Long> ctPivotCacheIdList = new ArrayList<Long>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < ctPivotCacheList.size(); i++) {
                        CTPivotCache ctPivotCache = ctPivotCacheList.get(i);
                        ctPivotCacheIdList.add(new Long(ctPivotCache.getCacheId()));
                    }

                    long firstPivotCacheId = firstPivot.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getCacheId();
                    for (int i = ctPivotCacheIdList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (ctPivotCacheIdList.get(i) != firstPivotCacheId) {
                            ctPivotCacheList.remove(i);
                        }
                    }

                    secondPivot.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setCacheId(firstPivotCacheId);
                    secondPivot.setPivotCache(firstPivot.getPivotCache());
                    thirdPivot.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setCacheId(firstPivotCacheId);
                    thirdPivot.setPivotCache(firstPivot.getPivotCache());
}
```

Thank you all